# Insert File.php inside another Page.php

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

Here is the Bootstrap that i using in a .php file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Example of Bootstrap 3 Accordion</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    .bs-example{
        margin: 20px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="bs-example">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">Title 1</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>call or insert fileA.php</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">Title 2</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>call or insert fileB.php</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">Title 3</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>call or insert fileC.php</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p><strong>Note:</strong> Click on the linked heading text to expand or collapse accordion panels.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Ok now im using this to call the files in Title 1 in the accordion
 but im getting a problem if i put in Title 2 in the accordion  the fileA.php is display here as well.

Any idea?

Comment: im using this to call the files `<?php include 'fileA.php';?>`

Comment: do `include('fileA.php');` inside the DIV that you want the information to be called into. Doing this throughout the page will automatically load all those pages. If you're trying to load them based off of a value. do an IF Statement something like `$var = 'yes'; if ($var === 'yes') { include('fileA.php'); } else { include('fileB.php'); }`